# Is there a way to use PageRenderer methods on a page with cachable and non-cachable extbase actions?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

If a page contains two Extbase plugins and one plugin calls a cachable action and the other a non-cachable action PageRenderer method calls to add CSS and JavaScript files do not work. There is no error message but the files are not added to HTML markup.

I tried to place the PageRenderer method calls into controller methods `initializeAction`, `initializeView` and `listAction`. It doesn't make a difference.

If the actions of both plugins are cachable or non-cachable PageRenderer method calls work as expected.

If I make the cachable action non-cachable and vice versa the PageRenderer method calls don't work either. It is not important which action is cachable or non-cachable.

I tried to use the modern way with HeaderAssets and FooterAssets sections in the Fluid template. Same problem here: Theses sections are not rendered if both cachable and non-cachable actions are called.

```php
/* @var $pageRenderer \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer */
$pageRenderer = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
$pageRenderer->addCssFile('my.css');
$pageRenderer->addJsFooterFile('my.js');
```

I know there are issues with caching and PageRenderer (USER and USER_INT objects). But I don't understand why the PageRenderer method calls fail with both cachable and non-cachable actions if they do work with only cachable or non-cachable actions. Is this the supposed behaviour? How can I make PageRenderer method calls work?

Comment: do you try to include the same files from both plugins? are the plugins related to each other?

Comment: CSS and JavaScript files are only included in one of the plugins, a customized plugin from extension _cw_twitter_. The other plugin that prevents inclusion of the files is a plain list plugin from extension _news_.

Comment: maybe a naming conflict as ext:news has the possibility to include social media buttons (which might remove/ block the include because of deactivation in news). I would try to change loading order of these extensions.

Comment: I tried to change the loading order of these extension. That didn't help. I checked the source code of extension _news_ and removed a lot of it to find the source of the problem. Unfortunately without success.
The only thing that makes inclusion of CSS and JavaScript files work is to make actions in both extension either cachable or non-cachable. In my case I could either remove `'Tweet' => 'list'` from non-cachable actions in _ext_localconf.php_ of _cw_twitter_ or add `'News' => 'list'` to non-cachable actions in _ext_localconf.php_ of _news_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding CSS or JavaScript files via PageRenderer doesn't work in extbase plugins with non-cachable actions at all. Or at least not reliable. The rendered output of a non-cachable action will only be added to the page template after the HTML markup of the page with the link and script tags is already fully rendered. Thus it is not possible to add additional CSS and JavaScript files. (Adding files via TypoScript is the way to go.)